# Trying to Package a Python package up for PYPI getting an invalid requirement error

Tags: python, pypi

Am trying to package a pyton3 program for pypi I'm getting as far as

```
python -m build --sdist --wheel --outdir dist/ .
```

and am getting the following error

```
raise InvalidRequirement(
pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at ""['tracew"": 
Expected W:(abcd...)
```

in my options section of setup.cfg I have

```
install_requires=['tracewrapper'],
```

any thoughts obviously happy to provide full stack trace if folks want it

Cheers

Comment: I'm guessing you have a quoting error earlier in your `setup.py`.

Comment: That's the exact text (Copied & pasted) suspect the tutorial I'm working from isn't that up to date as it doesn't mention setup.py

Comment: My bad, I mean a typo in your `setup.cfg` (sorry, sloppy reading). The legacy `setup.py` is still prevalent, but actually _older_ than `setup.cfg`. Can you link to whatever it is you are copy/pasting from?

Comment: @tripleee that's entirely possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.cfg`, unlike `setup.py`, is not Python; it's [INI](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#setup-cfg) config.

```
[options]
install_requires =
    tracewrapper
```

Ref: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html